# How to Convert from Geopoint to Latlng

Tags: flutter

[Geopoint -1.0255003501604503/119.48473403405048]

to Latlng flutter exp:

LatLng[-1.0255003501604503, 119.48473403405048]

Thank for Attention

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
late GeoPoint geoPoint;
double lat = geoPoint.latitude;
double lng = geoPoint.longitude;
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```